# Just for fun (it's fair)

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

Try make sense of the image below. The answer is ten letters in total.

---

[image]

Hint:

> [image]

Hint2:

> [image]

---

**Note:** I added a (4) and an (8). It doesn't affect the puzzle.

Comment: I think I have the rebus pretty much worked out but the squiggly lines make me think its supposed to sound like something else. Not sure what or how to apply it to the rest of the puzzle.

Comment: @cap rot13(bx, lbh'er ba gur evtug genpx gura. Ohg gur "fbhaq fvzvyne" bayl nccyvrf gb bar bs gur fdhnerf. Gur bgure fdhvttyl yvarf bhgfvqr, jung pbhyq gurl cbffvoyl zrna?  "fvzvyne ?")

Comment: haha i got it now

Comment: @cap ...Nice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rebus first picture:

> 14 Libra = 14 pounds = 1 stone ~= rock

The rebus second picture:

> SHE + ET = SHEET ~= paper

The rebus third picture:

> CHEERS sounds like SHEARS ~= scissors

The five arrows with numbers in parentheses

> represent throws of rock-paper-scissors. The numbers are the number of letters in each of the words: (4) = rock, (5) = paper, (8) = scissors. The arrow points from the loser to the winner.

Taking the corresponding letters gives us

> A WON DA GAME.
> Which is true because A won 2 of the 3 throws that weren't draws.

Comment: I was confused about rot13(jul sbhe pbeerfcbaqrq gb ebpx, rgp. hagvy V ernyvmrq gur ahzore vf gur ahzore bs yrggref va gur tvira ECF guebj!)

Comment: That's it! Well done.